# How to stub/mock a Javascript function with Jest?

Tags: javascript, arrays, unit-testing, jestjs, stub

I have a function that looks just like this. I wonder how can I mock stub the m and ms so that I can get the value I need and pass it into the map and return the array

```
async function getM() {
  const m = m.getInstance();
  const ms = await m.getAll();

  let array = [];

  if (ms && ms.length) {
    array = ms.map((m) => m.index);
  }

  return array;
}
```

This is my attempt:

```
describe("getM test", () => {
  it("should return the right number of m", () => {
    const ms = m.getAll().mockReturnValue(Promise.value([{
      0: {
        rate: 2
      },
      1:{
        rate: 1
      },
      length: 2
    }]));
    
  });
});
```

Comment: You're not mocking `m`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh I don't exactly know how to mock it because it is a getInstance() kind of function.

Comment: `m` probably needs to be an object which has a method `getInstance` which returns another object containing `getAll`. `getAll` can be a jest function.

Comment: how do you set up set getAll to be a jest function?

Comment: How did you import `m`?